# Select Case Statment single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need to return only on value from Then, But my query returns more 1s

```
    SELECT
CASE  WHEN S.ITEM_ID<>0 THEN 1
END AS "UomLevelEditable"
FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUEST_ITEMS S WHERE S.ITEM_Id =209 AND S.UOM_ID= 55
```

Comment: where is the sub query?

Comment: select unique case....

Comment: and also item_id + uom_id must be unique, or one of two in your table

Comment: then there is more than one row in the table that meets those conditions,  nut more importantly, if the Where condition specifies rows with `S.ITEM_Id =209`, then your conditional in the select case `WHEN S.ITEM_ID<>0` will always be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you issue solved by "UNIQUE" Key Word

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question

Comment: @user3359056 Still you need to work with table data, when you write such query, that means that your select unique data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *exactly* one row, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN S.ITEM_ID <> 0 THEN 1 END) AS "UomLevelEditable"
FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUEST_ITEMS S
WHERE S.ITEM_Id = 209 AND S.UOM_ID = 55;
```

If you want *at most* one row, then use `rownum = 1`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN S.ITEM_ID <> 0 THEN 1 END) AS "UomLevelEditable"
FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUEST_ITEMS S
WHERE S.ITEM_Id = 209 AND S.UOM_ID = 55 AND rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be helpful to you,I have Used Distinct below.

```
   SELECT
DISTINCT CASE  WHEN S.ITEM_ID<>0 THEN 1
END AS "UomLevelEditable"
FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.PO_REQUEST_ITEMS S WHERE S.ITEM_Id =209 AND S.UOM_ID= 55
```